# Meaning of fields in ip6tables logs

Tags: logs, ufw, ip6tables

I am parsing `ufw` logs, and running into limitations with the documentation that I am able to find for the `ip6tables` entries for `ufw`.

[This very nice blog post](https://logi.cc/en/2010/07/netfilter-log-format/) describes the iptables format well, but there are a few fields that I am not finding there, that AFAIU are IPv6-specific.

Here is a sample entry:

```
May 13 11:35:12 servername kernel: [ 4113.240744] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn SRC=nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn DST=nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn LEN=178 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=138
```

`HOPLIMIT` is like `TTL`, correct? What about `TC`, `FLOWLBL`, what are these? If they fit into some flags or options field, please let me know, it will impact how I parse. What would be even better would be a pointer to a wonderfully complete blog entry like that above...

And one more question, why are there 2 `LEN` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you shared is for IPv4, you are working with IPv6. So you need to google, the IPV6 documentation.

In short:
HOPLIMIT - Hop Limit - functional analog of Time To Live
TC - Traffic Class - defines what kind of information is in the packet (different flavors of control and data).
FLOWLBL - Flow Label - defines packet priority for routers.

I am not sure why the log contains two LEN fields, but most likely those are: header length and data length.
The header of the packet in IPv4 is a fixed format, in IPv6 it is partially modifiable with a variable length - hence a special header length field.

Here is a semi-nice list of fields with explanations.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internet-protocol-version-6-ipv6-header/

Much better would be a full-scale text book. I liked: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ipv6-essentials/0596001258/

Comment: Thank you, @white-owl, this is helpful. The G4G link gave me what I needed.